# How to send a secure mail merge with attachments using a secure file transfer tool?

Tags: r, attachment, email-attachments, file-transfer, mailmerge

Is there a secure file transfer tool which can also do mail merge? Or an R package that can do this?

I would like to send a secure mail merge with attachments to 145 people. Each attachment is customised to the recipient. I have a spreadsheet with a table of email addresses and the corresponding file attachment names that need to be sent.

The attachments need to be sent securely so in the past I have used a secure file transfer tool to send attachments customised to each of the 145 recipients. There is no mail merge feature in the secure file transfer tool (or API that I am aware of that can enable mail merge with attachments).

So each customised attachment was sent to the respective recipient separately, manually going through the send steps to send an attachment to each recipient.

Any hints or tips would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Bumping question in case anyone has ideas.